# Not able to ftp remote server anonymously

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I was not able to ftp to my remote server. I read Ubuntu doc to see how to resolve:
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html

Just now I installed vsftpd on my remote machine. Now when I run

```
ftp rs
```

it's saying :

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ ftp rs
Connected to ravi.com.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
331 Please specify the password.
530 Login incorrect.
Login failed.
ftp>
```

You see here it says to specify a password but it is not waiting for me to input password. Automatically it proceeds ahead and messages login failed.

How to resolve?
(Also I would appreciate if any material/link can be provided to me)

> EDIT

@dru please see the content of the configuration file

```
$ cat /etc/vsftpd.conf

# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=YES
#
# Run standalone with IPv6?
# Like the listen parameter, except vsftpd will listen on an IPv6 socket
# instead of an IPv4 one. This parameter and the listen parameter are mutually
# exclusive.
#listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default)
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
#write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
#chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
# This option specifies the location of the RSA key to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Comment: Can you post the config file (e.g. `/etc/vsftpd.conf`)?

Comment: I commented the line mentioned in `~/.netrc` file and now when I run `ftp rs`, it asks for username and password. `ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ cat .netrc`
`#default login anonymous password ravisingh1@rediffmail.com ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ `   But still it's not very clear as how `.netrc` works in ftp. Any suggestion please for clarification.

Comment: Your `vsftpd.conf` looks okay to me, you might want to uncomment the `#chroot_local_user=YES` line though for security reasons. I would suggest trying `apt-get purge vsftpd` and `apt-get install vsftpd` and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure why vsftpd.conf is quoted as looking okay above... The question asks why anonymous FTP doesn't work, and the line "anonymous_enable=NO" is in the config file, so thats one point of note.

Since the FTP client didn't bother to prompt you for a password, I'd assume its "auto" logging in as anonymous - since decades gone by the standard for this is the username "anonymous" or "ftp" and an email address as the password (which everyone always fakes).

I don't know what ftp client you have connected to your "ftp" command, but if its something like ncftp it will just anon login unless you put "-u username" in the parameters.

Thats my two cents on both parts anyway, need more to go on to understand your ftp client's behaviour really.

Comment: Thanks for you assistance. But please also note the comment (which is also somewhat an answer to my own question) I sent in 1st post. There is a file in my home directory: ~/.netrc. The content of the file was :        `default login anonymous  password ravisingh1@rediffmail.com`. When I commented it by putting a hash sign in the beginning of the line, then when I run `ftp rs`, it asks for username and password.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can tell how to know which ftp client is here that's connected to ftp command.

Comment: Try "which ftp" then ls -l the file it points to, its probably a symlink back to /etc/alternatives - "ls -l" that and see when it redirects back to (netkit-ftp for me).

Comment: Also, it's still not clear to me what the actual problem here is - the topic suggests "enabling anonymous logins in vsftpd" which I commented on, but the majority of the conversation is now more about an FTP client :)

Comment: The "standard" for username/password was exactly what I was looking for to resolve error "This FTP server is anonymous only. Login failed". Thanks!